# When adding an HTML5 manifest all my jQuery (mobile) AJAX requests fail with status 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have a working jQuery mobile application which does some simple `$.ajax` requests for static .json files. All is well until I add a manifest: merely changing `<html>` to `<html manifest="myapp.appcache">` breaks my ajax! Here's my manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css
images/ajax-loader.png
images/icons-18-white.png
jquery-1.6.4.js
jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js
```

I've tried adding:

```
NETWORK:
salesorg.*.json
```

Makes no difference. Serious de ja vu here but I don't know what the solution was.

Comment: Same problem here. GETs fail, but POSTs work. Would love to find a solution.

Comment: Please see answer in this topc:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824549/cannot-access-manifest-cached-files-with-ajax-from-webapp-saved-to-home-screen-i

Answer (score 1):

Create a ".htaccess" file and insert:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

The myapp.appcache file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css
images/ajax-loader.png
images/icons-18-white.png
jquery-1.6.4.js
jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js

NETWORK:
*
```